# Dynamics CRM 4.0: crmsvcutil.exe is erroring

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am using Crm 4.0 sdk to connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0. When using `CrmSvcutil.exe` to generate the entities it crashes with the following error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2 predicate)
   at CrmSvcUtil.Generator.GenerateEntityCode(XElement entityElement, String outputNamespace, DirectoryInfo outputDirectory, Boolean useLogicalNames, StreamWriter outputWriter)
   at CrmSvcUtil.Generator.Generate(IDictionary`2 arguments)
   at CrmSvcUtil.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

In particular its "SubscriptionTrackingDeletedObject" entity which is causing error.

I am using the following command line

```
crmsvcutil.exe /server:"http://MyServer/Org" /Out:"Xrm.cs" /namespace:"Xrm"/dataContextPrefix:"Xrm"  /useDisplayNames
```

When I try to generate the code for just one entity (other than one causing error) the tool runs to completion successfully.

I am bit stumped. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes the metadata for CRM conflicts with the actual table column sizes (if someone manually changed the size). I would suspect that is what is happening. Not sure how to workaround it though but hopefully this gives you some insight.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I was trying to avoid using Web Service but I think I will have to use that instead of Linq to CRM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS CRM 2011 CrmSvcUtil gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980962/ms-crm-2011-crmsvcutil-gives-error)

Comment: @Alex: We are using CRM 4.0 which is older version and want to phase out CRM totally but until that happens we need to support it (and not upgrade to later versions). I am using Web Service now instead of Linq to CRM and it worked wonderfully although there is more code to write to achieve same results.